# Swift Adding Button Action to TableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a button within my custom tableview cell that has the action of creating a Parse class if it isn't already created and applying the text of the label of the row that the button clicked occurred as the value for the "following" column and set the "follower" column value as the username of the current loggedin user. Currently I have an error at the `let usernameLabel` in the addUser IBAction that my Class does not have a member named `objectAtIndex`. What is the best way to achieve what I'm looking for?

I have created the outlets in SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var userImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addUserButton: UIButton!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        userImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        userImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        userImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        userImage.layer.cornerRadius = userImage.frame.width/2
        userImage.clipsToBounds = true


    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }



}
```

Here is my table functionality and the action that I tried to apply to my `addUserButton`:

```
import UIKit

class SearchUsersRegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    var userArray : NSMutableArray = []


    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        loadParseData()

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func loadParseData() {

        var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if let objects = objects {

                    println("\(objects.count) users are listed")

                    for object in objects {

                        self.userArray.addObject(object)

                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                println("There is an error")
            }
        }
    }



    let textCellIdentifier = "Cell"

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.userArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row

        var individualUser = userArray[row] as! PFUser
        var username = individualUser.username as String

        var profileImage = individualUser["profileImage"] as! PFFile

        profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (result, error) in

            cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: result)

        })

        cell.usernameLabel.text = username

        cell.addUserButton.tag = row

        cell.addUserButton.addTarget(self, action: "addUser:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell

    }


    @IBAction func addUser(sender: UIButton){

        let usernameLabel = self.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as! String

        var following = PFObject(className: "Followers")
        following["following"] = usernameLabel.text
        following["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser().username //Currently logged in user

        following.saveInBackground()
    }

    @IBAction func finishAddingUsers(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("finishAddingUsers", sender: self)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the usernameLabel is on the same contentView as the UIButton sender. If that's the case you can add a tag to the usernameLabel and do this

```
let usernameLabel = sender.superview.viewWithTag(/*Put tag of label here*/)
```

I'm on a mobile so I don't know if viewWithTag is the right name of the method, but it's something similar.

hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @Tobias, thanks for the answer. Sorry for the confusion on my end of your `/*Put tag of label here*/`, do you mean button outlet, which has a tag method?

Comment: So you can associate a Int value with any view `someView.tag = 10`. Then you can later find that view with it's tag `aSuperview.viewWithTag(10)`. You can also set this value in a storyboard or xib by selecting the view and going to the Attributes Inspect (option+cmd+4) then going down to the View section, under the Mode dropdown there should be a Tag textfield. So I would set the tag on the usernameLabel you're trying to get and use that.

Comment: Hey @Tobias, makes more sense to me now. So I selected my label in storyboard and change the value of that tag to 1. In my code I now use `let usernameLabel = sender.superview?.viewWithTag(1)` After that I want to take that labels text value and set it to my following["following"] = usernameLabel` object. When I try to use `usernameLabel.text` it doesn't appear to be possible and when I run just `following["following"] = usernameLabel` I get an error, `NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: 'PFObject values may not have class: UILabel'. I'm trying to set the text of the label as the value.

Comment: Glad to know you're making progress. You are now able to access the usernameLabel UILabel object. Now you are trying to associate usernameLabel.text a String value with your Parse object by doing `followers["following"] = usernameLabel.text`. The error you are getting means that the Parse object of class Followers doesn't accept a String value. You need to determine the type that it expects and assign a value of that type. Does it expect a PFObject of class user? Does it expect an array of Strings? Once you've answer this question you'll need to convert the username string to that type.

Comment: Yes, this needs to be as PFObject and this might be difficult for you to answer unless you are familiar with Parse, but when I set `following["following"] = usernameLabel as PFObject` I get an error `'UIView?' is not convertible to 'PFObject'` and `following["following"] = usernameLabel.text as PFObject` gives me `Cannot assign a value of type 'PFObject' to a value of type 'AnyObject'`.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not familiar with Parse. You might want to start a new question just about assigning the text to the Parse object. Thank you for teaching me that Parse was out there. I might have to use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are using `self` instead of `tableView`

```
let usernameLabel = self.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as! String
let usernameLabel = tableView.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as! String
```

However, this will still give you an error because `UITableViewCell` cannot be cast as a `String`.
This is a better option:

```
if let surtvc = tableView.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as? SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell {
    // surtvc.usernameLabel...
    // the rest of your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Hey @Allen Chau, thanks for your answer. I am getting an error for the `objectAtIndex` section of your code. Maybe that isn't the right method for this statement. Error: `SearchUsersRegistrationViewController does not have a member names 'objectAtIndex'`

Comment: @cphill That error is because the ViewController doesn't have that method. It has methods like `loadParseData` and `addUser:`

Comment: @cphill Oh sorry I assumed you were using a UITableViewController based on the methods. Is that not the case?

Comment: Hey @AllanChau I am using a UIViewController with a tableview. I plan on adding search to the view controller which is why I don't want to use a UITableViewController.

Comment: @cphill this could easily be added using a UISearchController or UITableViewController with a Textfield as the search bar. Regardless, I have updated my answer above which should answer your question. :]

Comment: Hey @AllanChau I understand that concept much better now, but I still get an error for your surtvc variable line (`if let surtvc = tableView....`). It says `Could not find member 'objectAtIndex'`

Comment: Oh sorry I put 'self' as well. I have updated my answer to use tableView